# How to Print in Vaadin

Tags: java, web, layout, web-applications, vaadin

I have a VerticalLayout filled with components in Vaadin. PLease i will to print this layout exactly as it is to an A4 paper. Any Idea how to do this, Code Sample will be great.

Comment: If you mean a simple print button, then you might try `JavaScript.eval("print();")` in your button click listener. Or do you want the user to download a PDF containing your layout?

Comment: Check out [Printing](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-printing.html) from the book of Vaadin

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of the [Vaadin doc](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-printing.html)…

> Printing the Browser Window
>
> Vaadin does not have special support for launching the printing in browser, but you can easily use the JavaScript print() method that opens the print window of the browser.

```
Button print = new Button("Print This Page");
print.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Print the current page
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("print();");
    }
});
```

> The button in the above example would print the current page, including the button itself. You can hide such elements in CSS, as well as otherwise style the page for printing. Style definitions for printing are defined inside a @media print {} block in CSS.

Comment: Is work good in vaadin 8, Do you know a workaround for vaadin 14 too?

Comment: @DuracellDeMonaco I suggest you post a new Question specifically for Vaadin Flow.

Comment: ok,thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754154/how-to-print-in-vaadin-flow

Answer (score 0):

There's no "built-in" API for printing in Vaadin.
You have to use the browser's native printing API.