# How to print pdf in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin-flow

I'm trying to print a PDF with Vaadin Flow, unfortunately I can't really get it to work or rather I don't know how to go about it.
I have found the following entry, but here is always the whole browser page printed I really want to print only a PDF.
Could someone please help me.

[How to Print in Vaadin Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754154/how-to-print-in-vaadin-flow)

Answer (score 2):

When I want to print a PDF file with Vaadin Flow, I use [Print.Js](https://printjs.crabbly.com).

First, I create a Javascript source file somewhere in the `frontend` directory, such as `frontend/imports/import-print-js.js`, which is used to import Print.Js in the next step. Put the following line in that file:

```
import printJS from 'print-js';
```

Then I add the Print.Js NPM package to the project and import its JS module by annotating the Java view/component class I'll be using to call Print.Js from as follows:

```
@NpmPackage(value = "print-js", version = "1.6.0")
@JsModule("./imports/import-print-js.js")
```

Then to print the PDF, use the Java code

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("printJS(%s)".formatted(PARAMETER_STRING));
```

where `PARAMETER_STRING` contains the parameters you need/want to print your PDF file. For instance, if you have a document `docs/mydocument.pdf` on your local server and you want to show Print.Js's user feedback modal dialog, your `PARAMETER_STRING` would be:

```
{printable:'docs/mydocument.pdf', type:'pdf', showModal:true}
```

For details on the parameters available, see the Print.Js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877878/377320 works too. A complete Vaadin 23+ solution follows:

```java
@Route
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private StreamRegistration pdfStream;
    public MainView() {

        add(new Button("Print", e -> print()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent);
        pdfStream = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getResourceRegistry().registerResource(new StreamResource("demo.pdf", () -> {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream("/home/mavi/Downloads/demo.pdf");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        pdfStream.unregister();
        super.onDetach(detachEvent);
    }

    private void print() {
        final String uri = pdfStream.getResourceUri().toString();
        System.out.println("PRINTING 2: " + uri);
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("// create iframe element\n" +
                "const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');\n" +
                "\n" +
                "// create object URL for your blob or file and set it as the iframe's src\n" +
                "iframe.src = $0;\n" +
                "iframe.name = 'pdf';\n" +
                "\n" +
                "// call the print method in the iframe onload handler\n" +
                "iframe.onload = () => {\n" +
                "    const pdfFrame = window.frames[\"pdf\"];\n" +
                "    pdfFrame.focus();\n" +
                "    pdfFrame.print();\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "iframe.hidden = true;document.body.appendChild(iframe);", uri);

    }
}
```