# How to Print with vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I would like to know if there is a way to print directly a message with no print preview in Vaadin 23.3

I´ve tried the next:

```
    try {
            PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            pjob.setJobName("Graphics Demo Printout");  // Nombre del archivo
            pjob.setCopies(1);
            PageFormat pageFormat = pjob.defaultPage();
            pjob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
                public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
                    String content = "Stuff to Print\\n" +
                            "Important stuff\\n" + 
                            "" + txtPrint.getValue().trim() + "\\n";
                    content += "Prueba de impresion";
                    
                    if (pageNum > 0) // we only print one page
                        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE; // ie., end of job

                    Font f = pg.getFont();
                    pg.setFont(f.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 12));
                    pg.setColor(Color.black);
                    pg.drawString(content, 100, 100);

                    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
            }, pageFormat);

            pjob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this doesn´t allow me to print in a regular way, because it´s doing like a drawing instead of writing. And for that, is only allowing me print in coordinates.

What I expect is to print a string and respect instructions like "\n"

Comment: Are you looking to print on the server (the machine that executes the Java code) or on the machine that runs the browser?

Comment: In the machine that runs the browser

Comment: In general you can't do this in a browser. It would be a disaster if random websites could just print stuff on your printer without asking you. As for your code example, that seems to be using the java.awt APIs which only allow you to print on the system the Java app runs on. For Vaadin you will have to implement a view with the content to print and then use the browser's print preview to let the user print that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754154/how-to-print-in-vaadin-flow?rq=2

Comment: Ok, then there is no way to print information without showing it to the user? This because I need to print sensitive information

Comment: You could generate a PDF on the server, let the user download the file and tell them to print it.